# Upload data on wit.ai

Tags: python, nlp, wit.ai

I have some data in my spreadsheet which has some expressions and intent entities for each expression. I wish to train wit.ai with this data. How shall I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Use the HTTP API of Wit.ai.

You can create an entity or add new expressions to your entities.

Note that intents are special entities in Wit.ai. In this case, the `entity` field of an intent is equal to "intent". Hence, you should use the following url to add an expression to an intent: `https://api.wit.ai/entities/intent/values?v=20160526`

The HTTP API doc can be found here: https://wit.ai/docs/http/20160526